# Covariance Matrix of Disks Pixels in Mathematica

Tags: image, matrix, wolfram-mathematica, covariance

I would like to compute the Covariance Matrix of the image below. Pixel based. That is considering each Black Pixel of the Disks as vectors.

While the units below are in centimeter, there are 32 pixels per cm on the screen I am using.

Ahead of the Covariance Matrix computation itself, I can`t figure out the way to obtain all the pixels vector.

[image]

```
frmXY = {{6.59, 1.59}, {33.41, 28.41}};

stim = {{10.85, 21.91, 0.97}, {16.8, 5.26, 0.97}, {11.78, 7.11, 0.97}, 
        {12.64, 14.13, 0.97`}, {20.24, 16.16, 0.97}, {29.51, 8.06,1.53}, 
        {22.42, 5.78, 1.53}, {27.13, 16.47, 1.53}}


Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick],White, Rectangle @@ frmXY, Black,
          Disk @@@ (stim /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {{a, b}, c})}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

Comment: Hmmm... you've been around long enough, 500. I'm going to have to ask you – _What have you tried doing for each of those points in the summary?_ Perhaps if you attempt first then each of those will either answer itself (from the help docs) or you can ask us when you're stuck.

Comment: @Yoda, I don`t understand how to obtain the Covariance Matrix. I have tried and could always post the things I have done. But they just don`t work. I don`t get the syntax for 8 vectors. Also Because they are disks, I am struggling to either weigh by the area or consider all the pixel located in each disk as a single vector. This is for the first part.  I am happy to post what I have done but it just does not work and while I have a clear vision of my problem I believe I might not have the right strategy, or use of the tools I know or the tools I could use

Comment: @Yoda, Also I find the help menu very good when I have already used the Function, that I am comfortable with it.

Comment: re: area/pixel of disks, you will have to tell us what you need the covariance matrix of - i.e., what quantity makes physical sense to your problem. If you can write the quantities as a matrix `X`, the covariance matrix of `X`, treating each _row_ as an independent vector is just `XX^T` (normally, you also subtract the mean, but you needn't if that's your convention. Also normalize by `nRows` or `nRows-1`, as per your conventions). You can also get mma to give you the covariance matrix (using standard definitions) using `Covariance`. Maybe describing the problem better in words might help...

Comment: p.s. I meant _column_ above...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not clear from your question as to what constitutes the random variable that describes your model/system and I don't understand what it is that you're trying to take the covariance matrix of.

However, here's a simple example showing how to obtain the covariance matrix and compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors (basically, reproduce your first plot).

```
list = RandomReal[
   MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {{6, 3}, {3, 3}}], {5000}];
sampleCov = Covariance@list;
{eigValues, eigVectors} = Eigensystem@sampleCov;

Show[ListPlot@list, 
 Graphics[{Red, Arrowheads[0.03], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ (eigValues eigVectors)}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You, did my Edit help at all ?

Comment: @500 I wrote this before your edit. I'm still not clear on what you mean by "pixel based" covariance matrix. You'll need an `N` dimensional vector and `M` observations of it to form an `NxN` covariance matrix. If you consider the black pixels of the disks as vectors, then each disk will have a different number of components in the vector and it doesn't make sense to take the covariance matrix of all the different set of vectors.

Comment: The only thing meaningful thing that I can think of here is to treat the `x` coordinate and `y` coordinate as random variables and the centers of the disks as independent observations of `x` and `y`. So you have a 2-dimensional Gaussian distribution with as many observations as the number of disks and you'll get a 2x2 covariance matrix. Does that sound like something that might make sense in your application here?

Comment: You showed me the way, I now understand Covariance and EigenSystem, and managed to apply it to my data.                             "Pixel Based" : Essentially I want to obtain the covariance matrix of the black pixels provided that there is 32 pixel for 1 cm both on the width and height. I hope this is clear. Thank You very much for your help !

Comment: this function does what I was looking for : pixelDisk[{x_, y_, r_}] :=
 Module[{
   xRange = Range[px*x - px*r, px*x + px*r, 1],
   yRange = Range[px*y - px*r, px*y + px*r, 1]
   },
  Select[
   Flatten[
    Function[
      lx, {xRange[[lx]], yRange[[#]]} & /@ 
       Range@Length@xRange] /@ (Range@Length@yRange), 1], 
   EuclideanDistance[#, px*{x, y}] < px*r &]]     with px=32. I am really sorry I was not clear previously... Thanks again for your help !

Comment: could you explain me this syntax : " (eigValues eigVectors) " Why no comas are needed.

Comment: @500 The eigenvectors have unit norm. Here I'm multiplying each eigenvector with its corresponding eigenvalue so as to scale it to the right length.

Comment: Thanks, i did not get that  " " was equivalent of * !